# Match column names to graph results in neo4j transactional REST response

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A very cool feature of the neo4j transactional REST api endpoint is that you can get [query results in graph format](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format). However, I'm having trouble figuring out which node matches which column name when there are multiple nodes returned. Based on my testing the order of the nodes is not consistent with the column order.

For instance, in the example given in the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format) the query ends with

```
RETURN bike, p1, p2
```

and the response (edited) includes

```
"graph" : {
    "nodes" : [ {
      "id" : "4",
      "labels" : [ "Bike" ],
      "properties" : {
        "weight" : 10
      }
    }, {
      "id" : "5",
      "labels" : [ "Wheel" ],
      "properties" : {
        "spokes" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "id" : "6",
      "labels" : [ "Wheel" ],
      "properties" : {
        "spokes" : 32
      }
    } ]
```

My question is, how do I know if the `Wheel` `p1` corresponds to the node with `id` 5 or the node with `id` 6? Again, I don't think the order is guaranteed, at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `p1` and `p2` are not nodes -- they are paths. In the [Cypher code](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format), one wheel is named `frontWheel` and the other is named `backWheel`.

To figure out the graph structure, you need to look at the `relationships` as well as the `nodes` in the returned `graph` data.

Here is another snippet from the results:

```
    "relationships" : [ {
      "id" : "0",
      "type" : "HAS",
      "startNode" : "4",
      "endNode" : "5",
      "properties" : {
        "position" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "id" : "1",
      "type" : "HAS",
      "startNode" : "4",
      "endNode" : "6",
      "properties" : {
        "position" : 2
      }
    } ]
```

From the `relationships` data (especially `startNode`, `endNode` and the `position` property), you can tell that node 4 is `bike`, node 5 is `frontWheel`, and node 6 is `backWheel`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the correction on the path vs node. I didn't look at the query closely enough. So if I understand your answer correctly, the the name of the nodes or relationships as assigned in the query is not used anywhere in the response. Instead one needs to re-assemble the graph structure to figure out what is what?

Comment: Yes. The node names used in a Cypher query are there for convenience, but are not persisted in the DB.